# Cannot find syntax error in spring-data-jpa query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem with my code, jpa tells me:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.example.demo.dto.TimbratureOfDay(DATE(data_timbratura), min(time(data_timbratur' at line 1
```

I'm trying to map the result set on a class of mine which isn't annotated as an entity, I know it can be done because I have before, I've checked several times because usually when this error occurs it just means that I forgot to add a space in the query when pasting it from mySQl workbench to the DAO but this time it doesn't seem to be the case, here's the method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.example.demo.dto.TimbratureOfDay(DATE(data_timbratura), min(time(data_timbratura)), max(time(data_timbratura))) "
            + "FROM timbrature "
            + "WHERE year(data_timbratura) = ?1 and "
            + "fk_employee = ?3 "
            + "and month(data_timbratura) = ?2 "
            + "GROUP BY DATE(data_timbratura)", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<TimbratureOfDay> getTimbratureOfMonth(int year,String month,Long idEmployee);
```

and here's the class:

```
public class TimbratureOfDay {
    private Date giorno;
    private Time entrata;
    private Time uscita;
    
    public TimbratureOfDay() {}
    
    public TimbratureOfDay(Date giorno, Time entrata, Time uscita) {
        super();
        this.giorno = giorno;
        this.entrata = entrata;
        this.uscita = uscita;
    }

    public Date getGiorno() {
        return giorno;
    }

    public void setGiorno(Date giorno) {
        this.giorno = giorno;
    }

    public Time getEntrata() {
        return entrata;
    }

    public void setEntrata(Time entrata) {
        this.entrata = entrata;
    }

    public Time getUscita() {
        return uscita;
    }

    public void setUscita(Time uscita) {
        this.uscita = uscita;
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT new com.example.demo.dto.TimbratureOfDay(` doesn't look like valid MySQL. You're doing a native query, not a JPQL one.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `nativeQuery=true` and using syntax of `JPQL`.
You can either set `nativeQuery=false` and use `JPQL` or set `nativeQuery=true` and use `SQL` in `MySQL` dialect.

Comment: if I  set it to false the application won't start and it says 'timbrature is not mapped'

Comment: @santocielo99 If you using `JPQL` the names in the `FROM` section should be a name of an entity you created in your Java code. You can see some nice examples here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Answer (score 0):

You can try with nativeQuery=false,  and at any time, you can set detail log level to dump the real SQL which is executed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).